# PDFJS Find and Naviage to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, pdf.js

We are using PDFJS to highlight/Find a text in PDF file. That works perfectly. Another functionality is to navigate to a particular page. We are trying to set CurrentPage property of PdfApplicationViewer. But it throws error like

> parentOffset not set. Cannot Scroll

Have attached the js code below.

```
 'use strict';

                if (!PDFJS.PDFViewer || !PDFJS.getDocument) {
                    alert('Please build the pdfjs-dist library using\n' + '  `gulp dist-install`');
                }

                // The workerSrc property shall be specified.
                //
                PDFJS.workerSrc = 'lib/pdfviewer/pdf.worker.js';

                // Some PDFs need external cmaps.
                //
                // PDFJS.cMapUrl = '../../node_modules/pdfjs-dist/cmaps/';
                // PDFJS.cMapPacked = true;

                var DEFAULT_URL = PdfUrl;
                var SEARCH_FOR = SearchWord; // try 'Mozilla';

                var container = document.getElementById('viewerContainer');

                // (Optionally) enable hyperlinks within PDF files.
                var pdfLinkService = new PDFJS.PDFLinkService();

                var pdfViewer = new PDFJS.PDFViewer({
                    container: container,
                    linkService: pdfLinkService,
                });

                pdfLinkService.setViewer(pdfViewer);

                // (Optionally) enable find controller.
                var pdfFindController = new PDFJS.PDFFindController({
                    pdfViewer: pdfViewer
                });
                pdfViewer.setFindController(pdfFindController);

                container.addEventListener('pagesinit', function () {
                    // We can use pdfViewer now, e.g. let's change default scale.
                    pdfViewer.currentScaleValue = 'page-width';
                    if (SEARCH_FOR) { // We can try search for things
                        pdfFindController.executeCommand('find', {
                            caseSensitive: false,
                            findPrevious: undefined,
                            highlightAll: true,
                            phraseSearch: true,
                            query: SEARCH_FOR,

                        });
                    }
                });

                // Loading document.
                PDFJS.getDocument(DEFAULT_URL).then(function (pdfDocument) {
                    // Document loaded, specifying document for the viewer and
                    // the (optional) linkService.
                    pdfViewer.setDocument(pdfDocument);
                    pdfLinkService.setDocument(pdfDocument, null);
                    PDFViewerApplication.page = parseInt(SearchPageNo);

                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix with setCurrenPage Option